# MediaCodec decoding AAC audio on Android - decodes but can't hear any output

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, aac, android-mediacodec

I can successfully decode AAC using the NDK AMediaCodec API, but no audio is playing.

Here's my configuration:

```
AMediaFormat_setString( format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm" );
AMediaFormat_setInt32( format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 2 );
AMediaFormat_setInt32( format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 44100 );
AMediaFormat_setInt32( format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_IS_ADTS, 0 );

uint8_t es[2] = { 0x12, 0x12 };
AMediaFormat_setBuffer( format, "csd-0", es, 2 );
```

And here's what I do to decode:

```
ssize_t inputIndex = AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer( decoder, kInputTimeout );
uint8_t* inputBuf = AMediaCodec_getInputBuffer( decoder, inputIndex, &inputSize );

// Copy AAC data into inputBuf ...

AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer( decoder, inputIndex, 0, aacSize, pts, 0 );

ssize_t outputIndex = AMediaCodec_dequeueOutputBuffer( decoder, &outputBufferInfo, kOutputTimeout );

if( outputIndex >= 0 )
{
    AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer( decoder, outputIndex, true );
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, and `outputBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs` is being updated appropriately, so it seems to be decoding. However no audio is being output. Is it right that `releaseOutputBuffer` does this for audio? I've tried setting it's `render` boolean parameter to both `true` and `false` but I get silence for both.

Does `MediaCodec` output audio like it does video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MediaCodec doesn't automatically render audio - the render parameter to releaseOutputBuffer doesn't do anything for audio. (See the Java documentation for the MediaCodec class for more explanations on these matters, that may be lacking in the NDK documentation.)

You need to manually take the decoded output buffer and feed it to either AudioTrack or OpenSL ES in order to play it back.